# Testing a pirobox (lightbox like) modal with Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, lightbox, watir

I'm writing tests for www.offdesk.com and when "sign up" anchor is clicked, it opens a pirobox modal window, at this point my irb works fine but I can't set text into the inputtexts inside it.

I wrote:

```
browser.link(:id, 'lkNovaConta').click()
browser.text_field(:id, "usuario_nome").wait_until_present
browser.text_field(:id, "usuario_nome").set("Test user")
```

but never passes the until_present, so as I have a JS var with the html content, I thought I had an index probelm, so I tryed:

```
browser.link(:id, 'lkNovaConta').click()
browser.text_field(:id => "usuario_nome", :index => 1).wait_until_present
browser.text_field(:id => "usuario_nome", :index => 1).set("Test user")
```

also tryed with index = 2, index = 0... but all have failed

Do you have any idea how to test it or any suggest to make this feature testable?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

$ gem list watir
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
watir-webdriver (0.3.9)

$ irb

> require "watir-webdriver"
 => true 

> browser = Watir::Browser.new
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x91f4b0ffb95e486 url="about:blank" title=""> 

> browser.goto "http://www.offdesk.com/"
 => "http://www.offdesk.com/" 

> browser.a(:id => "lkNovaConta").click
 => [] 

> browser.text_field(:id => "usuario_nome").set "test"
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
(...)

> browser.text_field(:id => "usuario_nome", :index => 1).set "test"
 => ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work for me...
My ruby and watir versions are different and I also executing the test but Uint Test with rake test:units.. so maybe theres is a concurrency problem at this point... trying to access the usuario_nome before it really shows up.

Comment: Perhaps try using Class instead of ID as the identifier?